# uploads folder as static using express not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

**NOTE**: **I have tried and seen other similar issues but none resolved my problem thus posting again, thanks.**

Hey everyone! I am trying to access the images uploaded in a folder at the backend/uploads directory which is marked as static but its not working as expected.

uplaodRoutes.js

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, "backend/uploads/");
},
filename(req, file, cb) {
 cb(
  null,
  `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
);
},
});

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
 const filetypes = /jpg|jpeg|png/;
 const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
 const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
 if (extname && mimetype) {
  return cb(null, true);
 } else {
   cb("Images only!");
 }
 }

 const upload = multer({
   storage,
 fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
  checkFileType(file, CB);
 },
 });

router.post("/", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  req.file.size = req.file.size / 1000;
  res.send(req.file);
});

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
app.use(
  "/uploads",
  express.static(path.join(path.resolve(), "backend/uploads"))
);
```

[image]

as we can see we cannot access it in browser.

Answer (score 0):

const upload = multer({

```
   **storage: fileStorageEngine,**  add fileStorageEngine Parameter
   storage: fileStorageEngine,
   fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
   **change from CB to cb**
   checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you kinldy elaborate it a bit, I am not getting this answer. thank you